# Update of requirement links on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible somehow to update all requirement links from (Successor/Predecessor) type to (Affected by/Affects) type automatically on project.

I didn't find any possible solution for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in solution to do that automatically. However, you can try to write a script to call the [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API to remove the `Successor/Predecessor` type links from a specify work item (`requirement` in your scenario), and then add the same links as the new type (`Affected by/Affects`).

- Reference [Remove a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#remove-a-link) sample to remove the `Successor/Predecessor` type links.
- Reference [Add a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#add-a-link) sample to add the links as the new type `Affected by/Affects`.

Once you done that for a specify work item, then you call another REST API ([Reporting Work Item Links - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/reporting-work-item-links/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)) to get all `Requirement` work items from the project, then change the type in a loop.